# How to preview colors when using the color picker in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, tools

When using Adobe Illustrator, how do I preview my changes when I'm using the color picker to change the color of an element?

Picking the color of an element is dependent on what's around it, so I'd like to see my color changes as I'm making them rather than having to click apply every time I'd like to see my work.

*Bonus points if you also know how to remove the outline that appears when an element is selected during this process. [That also interferes with choosing the correct color]

Answer (score 6):

Select the art and choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork` and play to your heart's content.

To hide the selection edges, simply choose `View > Hide Edges`. However, if you use `Recolor Artwork` the edges automatically get hidden when that dialog is open.

Comment: This doesn't preview anything. You still can't see the color change until you apply it.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites no clue what your'e going on about. It previews just fine here.

Comment: Then go back in time to March when I made the comment and see if you can reproduce the issue with the build of Adobe Creative Cloud I was using. Nothing was updating until applying it. That's why I wrote the comment. I think it's clear what I'm going on about.

Comment: I realize it's an old comment :) Thread was bumped today. But recolor art has *always* previewed colors here since it was implemented in CS4 without the need to "apply" them.

Comment: Hard to say at this point but I am sure the feature by design works as you describe, although it wasn't working for me at the time for whatever reason.

Comment: One potential source of confusion here, based on what I observed: If you use the sliders in the "Recolor Artwork" panel then the colors are updated live, but if you click the color box to enter the color picker, the colors will not update live when choosing a new color.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a global swatch.

1. Select your object
2. Drag its fill colour from the toolbar into the `Swatches` panel
   (`Window > Swatches`)
3. Double-click the swatch
4. Check the `Global` checkmark
5. Check the `Preview` checkmark
6. Choose your `Color Mode` of choice
7. Color pick away.

For the bonus points, to hide your selection lines, hit <kbd>Control/Option</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or choose `View > Hide Edges`.

Comment: This method doesn't allow you to use the usual Color picker, but only gives three sliders to adjust with?

Comment: @o01 Be aware that the colour picker is inaccurate, as opposed to the Color panel (which the 'three sliders' are lifted from).

Comment: Here in the future of 2021, this seems to still be the case. Color picker: no preview. Recolor Object: cumbersome but does preview and is sort of like the Color picker. Swatch manipulation: cumbersome, and uses 3 of 1-dimensional controls, instead of 1+2 in the pickers' models. :(